# AWS amplify datastore with flutter for desktop alternative?

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, offlineapps

I am going to develop an App with AWS amplify with Offline capabilities (using datastore and appSync).

On AWS Amplify Flutter doc (https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/q/platform/flutter/) I read :

The stable release of Amplify Flutter currently supports iOS, Android, Web, Windows, MacOS, and Linux as target platforms. Currently Push Notifications and **Datastore are supported for only iOS and Android**.

I would like to be able to store data using **datastore** even if i am on Flutter Desktop (Windows, MacOs, Linux) and Flutter Web.

How could I develop my app ? What alternative / solution can I use for Flutter Desktop and Web ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using AWS Amplify API with DynamoDB + OpenSearch (formerly known as ElastiSearch). Amplify Datastore is based on DynamoDB, but it still has some limitations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i am too late to answer

Since AWS DataStore currently has some limitation, you can try the following combination:

1. graphql flutter package + any other third party DB like Hive, Sembast which supports all platforms
2. AMS Amplify API + any other third party DB like Hive, Sembast which supports all platforms
3. Seperate the code for Mobile and Other platforms, and use approach 2 for those platforms

On a personal note in one of my older projects, i was using a combination of AWS Amplify [Mostly for Subscriptions only] + graphql flutter package [For Queries and Mutation] + Hive for local storage

This way i am not totally dependent on a service and can easily switch as per my needs